# Error while setting volume on SoundEffectInstance

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xna, windows-phone

I am seeing an error be reported quite frequently in my application. I know where it is happening, I just don't know why. The app plays sound effects (not background music), I am using Xna.Audio and I have a timer to call FrameworkDispatcher.Update() in regular intervals. I am using SoundEffect.CreateInstance so I can I have the sound effect loop. It looks like an error happens when changing the volume. I don't know WHY though. Are there known instances when this can fail?

**Function** ::: Offset

---

**xxx_RaiseException** ::: 32
**WatsonUnhandledManagedException** ::: 300
**Dbg_NotifyManagedException** ::: 136
**FirstPassException** ::: 1044
**TransitionStub** ::: 0
**Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Helpers.ThrowExceptionFromErrorCode** ::: 76
**Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio.SoundEffectInstance.set_Volume** ::: 232
**Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio.SoundEffectInstance..ctor** ::: 232
**Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio.SoundEffect.CreateInstance** ::: 192
**AgiliTrain.PhoneyTools.Media.SoundEffectPlayer..ctor** ::: 96
**WildSafari.ClassicModeGame.animalVisibleTimer_Tick** ::: 344
...snip....

For those asking, here is more code. The SoundEffectPlayer takes a SoundEffect, creates an instance, and kicks off the XNA FrameworkDispatcher (via the GameTimer). This code is taken from PhoneyTools, so go check out the codeplex project if you need more context. When I want to play an effect, I just new up a SoundEffectPlayer, and pass in what I want.

```
public class SoundEffectPlayer
{
    GameTimer _xnaTimer = new GameTimer();
    SoundEffectInstance _effect = null;
    public float _duration;

    public SoundEffectPlayer(SoundEffect effect, bool loop)
    {
        _effect = effect.CreateInstance();
        _effect.IsLooped = loop;
        _duration = (float)effect.Duration.TotalSeconds;
    }

    public void Play(float volume)
    {
        _xnaTimer.Start();
        _effect.Play();
        _effect.Volume = volume;
    }

    public void Stop()
    {

        _effect.Stop(true);
        _xnaTimer.Stop();
    }
}

public class GameTimer
{
    DispatcherTimer _timer = new DispatcherTimer()
    {
        Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50),
    };

    public GameTimer()
    {
        _timer.Tick += new EventHandler(_timer_Tick);
    }

    void _timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        if (!_timer.IsEnabled) _timer.Start();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        if (_timer.IsEnabled) _timer.Stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure why this exception is thrown, however if you already have a reference to an instance of the SoundEffect class, you could call the overload of the Play method that also accepts volume.

Comment: Yeah, but only the soundeffectinstance has the loop property. A soundeffect doesn't. it it was supposed to say that, but I had volume on my mind when I wrote the question, and messed up. Fixed it, thanks.

Comment: Is this exception reproducing consistently? also does it happen on Windows or only for wp7?

Comment: I can't repro it, but I get several on them reported every day.

Comment: i dont think i understood, what do you mean got several of them reported every day? where are they reported? this is not an exception that is being thrown in your code?

Comment: No, these are not exceptions I am catching. For people who opt-in to send MS data on their phone, unhandled exceptions are included. You can see them via the dashboard on the AppHub site. So several are reported per day just like the one above.

Comment: I see. Does it have any noticable impact on the game you're running then?

Comment: considering it only reports unhandled exceptions, I assume it causes a crash

Comment: Did you manage to reproduce this even once yourself ? If not, do u get any extra information with these reports on AppHub? for example, happens on specific device model, etc.

Comment: no. i can't repro, and what i have above is basically what i get.

Comment: What device are u using? I will be happy to try it out on my HTC HD7. May be a bug in the WP7 or some weird scenario happening on specific device?

Comment: im on the focus. the game is WildSafari (just grab the trial). the game is for 1-2yr olds so you wont find it fun :)

Answer (score 1):

Trying to help out, although i don't have a valid fix...

The setter property for SoundEffectInstance is not as simple as one might think:

```
  set
        {
            lock (this.voiceHandleLock)
            {
                if (this.IsDisposed)
                {
                    throw new ObjectDisposedException(base.GetType().Name, FrameworkResources.ObjectDisposedException);
                }
                if ((value < 0f) || (value > 1f))
                {
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value");
                }
                Helpers.ThrowExceptionFromErrorCode(SoundEffectUnsafeNativeMethods.SetVolume(this.voiceHandle, value));
                this.currentVolume = value;
            }
        }
```

Basically the part we're after comes in the line before last.

If the call from **SoundEffectUnsafeNativeMethods.SetVolume** returns any code smaller than 0, the exception you're getting will be triggered.

Here's what's happening inside the unsafe method:

```
public static unsafe int modopt(IsLong) SetVolume(uint soundEffectInstanceHandle, float volume)
{
    lock (SoundEffectSubsystemSyncObject)
    {
        if ((soundEffectInstanceHandle != 0) && (soundEffectInstanceHandle != uint.MaxValue))
        {
            CHandleTable* tablePtr = ?g_pTable@CHandleTable@@0PAV1@A;
            KernelSoundEffectInstance* instancePtr = CHandleTable.LookUp<class Microsoft::Xna::Framework::Audio::KernelSoundEffectInstance>((CHandleTable modopt(IsConst)* modopt(IsConst) modopt(IsConst)) ?g_pTable@CHandleTable@@0PAV1@A, soundEffectInstanceHandle, 0);
            if (instancePtr == null)
            {
                return -2147024809;
            }
            return **(((int*) instancePtr))[0x34](instancePtr, volume);
        }
        return -2147024809;
    }
}
```

You can try to surround the creation of _effect.CreateInstance with try...catch and rethrow a more comprehensive and helpful exception that will contain for example, information about the SoundEffect object which you're trying to create (basically you can note down all of its field's values for inspection. (not sure that what you get from MS is only a stack trace or the actual exception messaage).

It seems that on WP7, the call to set the volume goes to some OS pointer table that does some magic behind the scenes and looks for the sound effect handle in this table.

If for some reason it is not found or something similar (don't know why, maybe we can take it with XNA developers), it will throw this exception you're getting.

I know this is not a solution but maybe this is a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the exception should not be thrown for the situation you are describing, as long as you built the XNA compatibility layer as it should be (details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg442302%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)).

However, I noticed that you are using `PhoneyTools.Media.SoundEffectPlayer` - what for? It might be the cause of the problem in your situation.

Also, you seem to have ambiguous references - `effect` and `_effect` - which one are you working with when playing content?

Comment: It is _effect. Typo'd when i put in the code. I am using the tool mentioned because that library wraps up the xna library up for me. I could do it myself, but why bother when it is done already.

Comment: Can't seem to reproduce the error at the moment. Are you testing on a device or in the emulator? Try removing extra references and only keep the native (WP7) references to .NET Base Assemblies. You don't need any third-party tools to work with a SoundEffectInstance for this test scenario.

Comment: Also would be helpful - show your FrameworkDispatcher timed loop code.

Comment: I can't repro this either. I am seeing the error reported from users via the app hub. I'll post the code in an hour or so when I'm at my PC.

Comment: How many reports are you exactly getting with this error? If you cannot reproduce it directly, there might be secondary behavior that is triggering it (e.g. unexpected thread termination and such).

Comment: about 20/day with a user base of only 125-ish

Comment: Is ti causing an application crash or it's simply caught?

Comment: @Joe let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2077/discussion-between-dennis-delimarsky-and-joe)